# How to display a content (form) from one url in different html page?

Tags: html

I am very new in html and web programming. I have a subscription form at www.is.gd/podpiska, I want to show it at our facebook fanpage. so people don't have to go to other pages, but can directly fill this form in our fanpage. In facebook I should use html, so how to display this form in another html document? Could you help with coding, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using an iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://www.is.gd/podpiska" width="617" height="400" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Not shure if you can call an form post from facebook, but you could iframe it into a HTML tab on facebook, then redirect to your site with the value parameters.